# The setSize() Method in my JFrame class is not working due to an API error

Tags: java, methods, jframe

i was working with the JFrame class and i was trying to create an empty frame,but when i try to use the setSize() method,it shows some API error,something like Usage of API documented as @since 1.6+9
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1baE.png)

I just want to create an empty frame but the method i need to set the size for the frame is giveing an error related to API

Comment: I can’t see any immediate reason why it shouldn’t work - but assuming it did, you’d probably not see anything anyway (other then a empty window) as you’re adding components after making the window visible - best to set the window visible only once you’ve established the base ui

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You should use with Dimension class as parameter.

```
jframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
jframe.setSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
```